# Moving an unbreakable equation from one line to another

Tags: equations, line-breaking

I have an equation that is being split between two lines. I would like to solve this by making it unbreakable. However, if I do this, it overflows into the margin. How can I force the unbroken equation into the second line, where there is more space?

With curly braces, `${\Delta V = N_\Phi \left(V_{11}(0)-V_{12}(0)\right)}$`, the equation overflows into the margin

[image]

Without the curly braces, `${\Delta V = N_\Phi \left(V_{11}(0)-V_{12}(0)\right)}$` splits the equation between two lines

[image]

Comment: You don't need the braces, by the way. If you want it kept together, you can/should use `\mbox{$...$}`. Try with `\linebreak[4]\mbox{$...$}`.

Comment: Thank you! The linebreak solution is exactly what I had been looking for. One follow-up question - why is mbox preferred over the braces?

Comment: Alternatively, you can simply say `\break` just before your `$\Delta V = ...$` But this would not be pleasing to look at (as far as TeX is concerned: It chooses to break after `=` instead of breaking before the `\Delta V` for a reason, because the latter is “worse” than the former)

Comment: Braces by themselves form a group, which is used for local definitions and parameters; nothing to do with line breaking.  Boxes (of which there are many varieties) are unbreakable.

Comment: Another disadvantage to ```break``` is that if, say, you submit for publication, it is likely that the journal's linewidth will be different to yours, and you could end up with an unnecessary and undesirable line break. Many journals' line widths are wide enough to accommodate your equation - you don't want to force a break and leave a half-empty line on the previous line.  It is safer to use a box or you could force the math not to break with ```\nobreak```. (```\nobreak``` can become a little whackamole at times, but if Latex chooses a particularly bad place to break, you can suppress that.)

Comment: What's the problem if the equation is split at the equals sign? Do you perhaps mind if a word is split across lines? If the splitting is really bad (it isn't), rephrase the paragraph. For instance `is obtained by taking the limit for $q\to0$`, which is also better English.

Comment: This is en example of an equation that a journal copyeditor might mark for changing to an unnumbered display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the braces. Braces in general are used to provide some form of localisation or scope within which definitions are made/changed locally, unless explicitly set to be `\global`. Specific to math, braces also change the type within the construction to ordinal. See, for example, the difference in spacing between `a + b` and `a {+} b`.

If you want it kept together, you can/should use `\mbox{$...$}`. `\mbox` (short for `\makebox`) creates an unbreakable box for its argument. Then you can insert a (large) negative penalty before the box to encourage line breaking at that point using `\linebreak[4]`.